# How to replicate the pandas explode() functionality with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pandas, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm automating my google sheets in app scripts. I came across a scenario where one cell has multiple values. I want to `explode` it as in python.

Example input and output:

```
input = [["Hi",12,"One line
two line
three line", "God"],["Bye",13,"check","man"]]
output = [["Hi",12,"One line","God"],["Hi",12,"two line","God"],["Hi",12,"Three line","God"],["Bye",13,"check","man"]]
```

Following is my partial attempt

```
var final = y.map(r => {
    return r.map(x => {
      if(x.toString().indexOf("/n") > -1)
      {
        x = x.toString().split("/n");
      }
      return x;      
      });
  });
```

Comment: Missing input sample data, expected ouput, what you try.

Comment: provide input data and expected output at least.

Comment: Added input and output

Comment: Fix syntax errors in your example and show what you've tried.

Comment: Fixed the syntax errors in the example. I tried a solution but unable to figure it out. This was my partial attempt.

Comment: To start with, new line in js is `\n`, not `/n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce` to loop: `split` the string by new line `\n`, `map` the split array and join it to  the parent row and the previous accumulator and `flat`.

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 

const input = [["Hi",12,"One line\ntwo line\nthree line", "God"],["Bye",13,"check","man"]];
const output = input.reduce((acc,[a,b,c],i) =>  [acc,c.split("\n").map(sc => [a,b,sc])].flat() ,[]);
console.log(output);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```